In the Passkey implementation, how would a user recover his account if the server does not store any secret?
I've read in multiple articles that one benefit of passkey over password is that in the passkey implementation the server only stores the public key, therefore, the user won't lose any secret even if the server is compromisd.
However, I wonder in this case, what if the user lost his own private key and won't be able to authenticate himself to the server any longer. How would the user authenticate himself to the server to recover his account? There got to be some secrets about the user that are stored at the server, am I right?

I believe you'd rely on standard account recovery techniques, like via email or a recovery code.

Then this means the server still keeps some secret of the user, making the claim that "server does not store any user secret" a gimmick, right?

Well I haven't read into passkeys properly, but I'm pretty sure they're always used with a password attached to the account still (currently) rather than eliminating passwords completely, so yes. The difference with the recovery method is that the user isn't generating it, and you may be able to use a different device to log in rather than a code sent your email, etc. The point of passkeys is to avoid the user generating a weak secret/reusing secrets and to protect against phishing. It could also be more user friendly/allow quicker authentication, although I don't think that's true at present.
